# Is there anyway to print git branch info in html file

Tags: html, .net, git, deployment

My team and I work in a lot of branches and put them on different environments. We want to be able to print out the branch somewhere in the footer of our site.

Is there a file I can parse automatically or a way I can get that info without adding it manually?

We use git and .NET/C#

Comment: can you consider using cgit or gitweb

Comment: If you're generating the html yourself and serving directly from the repo's worktree you can `sed s,.*refs/heads/,, .git/HEAD` for the current checkout.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a simple filter:
http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

Git sym-ref is the command you would want to use. If you are using any build scripting, this can be used to add the branch name to the compiled code.